# how to increase page load speed

Tags: html

I have designed  [This site](http://softwareservicesindia.com/Pradnnya_blog/wordpress_site/?page_id=1290) .The page load speed is very low.I found online site [load time](http://loads.in/) which tells the load time of the site.As well as it gives the other statistics .

The page load time statistics snapshot is as folows:

[image]

my question is how can i decrease the page load time?Since it becomes very irritating if the page load time is more then 2 sec..

Comment: It seems to me that the webhosting service you're using itself is slow. a 1.5 kb file should not be taking in the order of 1 second to load.

Comment: ok Oday Mansour ..but even if the images are large enough like ranging from 450-100kb ..it should take 1 sec if the web hosting service is fast enough??..

Comment: 1 second for 450 KB is not bad, 1 second for 10 KB is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is really a programming question but one problem I see is that your images are too large in terms of file size.

These images are rather large for example:

http://softwareservicesindia.com/Pradnnya_blog/wordpress_site/wp-content/themes/deep-red/img/bgbody.gif (145kb)

http://softwareservicesindia.com/Pradnnya_blog/wordpress_site/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/he12.bmp (450kb)

http://softwareservicesindia.com/Pradnnya_blog/wordpress_site/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/slid11.bmp (1mb)

http://softwareservicesindia.com/Pradnnya_blog/wordpress_site/wp-content/themes/deep-red/uploads/Istpanelfinal.jpg (303kb)

http://softwareservicesindia.com/Pradnnya_blog/wordpress_site/wp-content/themes/deep-red/uploads/TA_UnionSTN4.jpg (311kb)

You can start by using a program like Adobe Photoshop to [save your images "for web."](http://graphicdesign.about.com/od/howto/ss/save_for_web_all.htm) You might also want to look into converting those bitmaps and GIFs into PNGs. You may also want to make your JPEG images progressive.

If you don't have access to Photoshop, a free alternative that can "save for web" is [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/).

edit: You might want to look into using some CSS to make a 1 pixel tall image repeat on the x-axis. You'd lose your gradient though.

Something like the following should work:

```
background-image:url(../images/gradient.gif);background-repeat:repeat-x;
```

Comment: True, some images are large, but you can see a lot of the lag comes from tiny files. There's obviously something wrong with where he's hosting his content.